# Profiling a code which exists in the middle of runtime

Tags: python, profiling

I am trying to profile a function's runtime with **cProfile**.

```
import cProfile
import pstats
import time

def foo(n):
    time.sleep(2)
    res = 0
    exit()
    for i in range(100000):
        res = res *1024+res



with cProfile.Profile() as pr:
    foo(n=1)  

pr.dump_stats('my_data.dat')


with open("my_data.dat","w") as f:
    p = pstats.Stats("my_data.dat",stream=f)
    p.print_stats()
```

Notice that I exit in the middle of the function,

Is there a way to config a profiler which on a Kill signal will save the results which it accumulated to a certain file?

AFAIK the dump occurs only **after** the function has successfully run.

I am doing this because I am profiling a performance issue, where the function takes too long to run, and need to find a way to run it sometime so I can find bottlenecks.

I can't wait until the function finishes because it may take hours.

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are multiple ways to do this.

First of all, I need to point out that cProfile is not gonna help you in your current `foo` function, because cProfile's minimum unit is function. Of course I would assume that your actual code is much more complicated than this and actually has multiple function entries.

So, for solutions.

`atexit` is a useful builtin library to handle this situation. You can do

```
import atexit
@atexit.register
def your_exit_routine():
    # stuff you want to run before exiting
```

`atexit` will work if you exit by `exit()`. It may not work in some other cases.

You can try `signal` module as well, which handles system signals, for example SIGKILL or SIGTERM.

```
import signal
signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, your_exit_routine)
```

This is pretty handy when you do CTRL+C to send a SIGTERM signal.

However, it becomes much more complicated when it comes to multi-thread or multi-process. In that case, I would recommend to use [viztracer](https://github.com/gaogaotiantian/viztracer), which supports multi-thread and multi-process and can visualize your program.

Actually, maybe it would be interesting to use it even on the cases that cProfile can deal with. It handles the exiting cases for you and has a pretty interface :)